# Did i miss something? HTML > Body - resize event

Tags: javascript, html

Usual way to add resize event (to listen window size changed) is this:

```
//works just fine
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){console.log('w')}, true)
```

but I want to add this event handler to `document.body` or even better to `document` (**don't ask me why, but i can't use window**)

```
//this dosn't work
document.body.addEventListener("resize", function(){console.log('b')}, true)

//this also dosn't work
document.addEventListener("resize", function(){console.log('d')}, true)
```

the problem is that this dosn't work. I really don't understand why? MB i missed something?

this works ( but ones again i want to use `addEventListener` )

```
document.body.onresize = function(){console.log('a')}
```

**So why `document.addEventListener("resize", function(){console.log('d')}, true)` doesn't work?**

---

**UPD #1**

Is there a way to capture window.onresize on something other that window?

**UPD #2**

And if `window` is the only object that get resized then WHY this works? o_O

```
document.body.onresize = function(){console.log('a')}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Mozilla Docs says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onresize)

"Any element can be given an **onresize attribute**, however only the window object has a **resize event**. Resizing other elements (say by modifying the width or height of an img element using script) will not raise a resize event."

please check [A working example](http://jsfiddle.net/MZfQ2/2/)

```
function winResize(e){
 console.log('window reiszed',e);

  //body resize when width increases
 document.getElementById('content').innerHTML+='<div style="width:900px;background:green;border:1px solid red">'+Date()+'</div><br/>';
}

function docResize(e){
 cosole.log('document resized');   
}

function bodyResize(e){
 console.log('body resized');
}

window.addEventListener("resize", winResize);
document.body.onresize=bodyResize;
```

**Edits:**
  If you stop events bubble document.body.onresize event will not be invoked: e.g

```
 function winResize(e){
     console.log('window reiszed',e);
     e.stopImmediatePropagation()
   }
```

**Update: **

a) First thing is to understand is that  resize event will be propagated from 
    [`window > document > body`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow)  and if you have defined resize event on all of the above nodes and [others](http://help.dottoro.com/ljorlllt.php) the event will be propagated down and each one will be invoked

b) when you ask difference b/w `window.resize` and `[body/document].onresize` is that 
      `window.resize` event is standard event defined in html4 specification and [body/document].onresize was available as nonstandard event (some browsers implemented but not all)
 But latter onresize event is added in [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/body.html)  to body.

Just to satisfy yourself go to [w3c validation site](http://validator.w3.org/) and validated following html using Doctype
  `html 4.01 strict` , you will see it will complain at onresize attribute :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
   <html><head><title>test</title></head> 
   <body onresize="somefunc()">
    <div> On resize validation </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

c) **conclusion.** 
      window.addEventListener()  comes with Dom level 2 event specifications only [add events listern for events](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/dom/addeventlistener.html) specified in that specification( Dom level 3 event also support this) , [read DOM levels.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM_Levels) & [this](http://help.dottoro.com/ljeuqqoq.php)

Comment: ok if "only the window object has a resize event" WHY `document.body.onresize` works? o_O

Comment: actually `window.resize` event is propagated down to `document.body` element. please check my edits

Comment: ok I get it, but why `addEventListener` doesn't work on `document.body` ?

Comment: Tnx.. This the most detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You should actually look at the anatomy of the browser and see which object has which events, window has a resize event which triggers when there is change in the size of the window, a document resides inside a window object its like `window->document->elements` and each in the hierarchy has thier own events.

Comment: read UPD #1 ( basically i want to capture resize event of window, on the any object other then window ) ( if you catch my idea )

Answer (score -2):

This one worked for me, using jQuery:

```
var windowWidth  = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height()
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
        windowWidth  = $(window).width();
        windowHeight = $(window).height();
}, false);
```