# Maximise and minimise buttons not triggering effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a javascript file, which I am using to determine the layout of my webpage, and also to fit font to certain divs. Here is my javascript code:

```
/*
use class fittextpara to fit text in a paragraph
use class fittexthead to fit text in a paragraph
*/
var stylesheet = document.getElementById("site_structure");
var ratio;

//when the page loads, set its layout by changing address of css file
layout();
document.body.onload = function(){
    font("fittextpara" , 8);
};
//on resize, change font and layout
document.body.onresize = layout_and_font;

function layout_and_font(){
    layout();
    font("fittextpara" , 8);
}

// function to change layout
function layout(){
    //handling the layout
    ratio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    //normal
    if(ratio <= 2 && ratio >= 1.3)
        stylesheet.setAttribute("href" , "normal.css");
    //mobile
    else if (ratio < 1.3)
        stylesheet.setAttribute("href" , "mobile.css");
    //widescreen
    else 
        stylesheet.setAttribute("href" , "widescreen.css");
}
// function to fit font: enter the class name and scale factor
function font(classname , scale_factor){
    //handling the text
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(classname)[0];
    if(x != null){
        if (x.clientHeight <= x.clientWidth)
            x.style.fontSize = (x.clientHeight / scale_factor) + "px";
        else
            x.style.fontSize = (x.clientWidth / scale_factor) + "px";
    }
}
```

The code is working nicely, except in one situation: when I am resizing my browser window using the maximise/minimise buttons, the layout is changing, but the font-size(which depends on the width and height of the div, as seen in the `fonts` function) is not. I tried setting a time-interval of 500 milliseconds, to delay the execution of the fonts function, but still no change.

For reference I am using Mozilla Firefox as my browser. It seems to me that when I am resizing the browser window using the maximise/minimise button, the code is not able to detect the new height/width of the div.

Comment: Have you tried using `window.onresize` instead of `document.body.onresize`. You can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did i miss something? HTML > Body - resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137629/did-i-miss-something-html-body-resize-event)

Comment: @Eisenheim, yes, I have tried that as well. However, I am still getting the same issue.